# Void a Paypal order with CAPTURE intent

Tags: php, paypal, checkout, paypal-rest-sdk

I am building an e-commerce and I'm using paypal checkout as a payment method.

I am having some trouble handling some edge cases around product availability.

To avoid multiple people buying the same product, I have two strategies:

1. **Block the product when a customer start the paypal checkout process and prevent anyone else to buy it.**
   The problem with this approach is that I want to avoid someone starting the paypal process, never completing it and 'blocking' the product without actually buying it. I could solve it by **voiding the paypal order** after a certain timeout (something like 5 minutes)
2. **Check the product availability at the end of the checkout process**. This would work great, but **I would need to void the paypal order** instead of capturing it in case the product is not available anymore

In both cases, there are some circumstances when *I need to void the paypal order*, and I don't know how to do it.

[Here, in the official documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/best-practices/simplify-order-cancellations/) they suggest to [void the authorized payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#authorizations_void), but this doesn't work for my use case:

- I use a `capture` payment, because I don't need the `authorization` flow
- I don't have an authorization ID

I think my situation should be a standard one, but I couldn't find anything here on stackoverflow or in the documentation about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to void an intent:capture.

No such call exists because it is entirely superfluous and unnecessary.

Regardless of whether or not it has been approved, simply do not capture it.

TL;DR Nobody needs to know you aren't going to do it. Just *don't do it.*

Comment: i disagree, there could be an unseen bug in the code where it accidentally gets captured. It could have been mitigated if only such were voided